# What is the collective name for Basic, Digest, NTLM and Kerberos authentication?

Tags: forms-authentication, kerberos, ntlm, digest

Is it correct use term "Challenge-response authentication" for Basic, Digest, NTLM and Kerberos authentication?

Is cookies/ASP.NET forms authentication is also a Challenge-response authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**: no, HTTP Basic is not challenge/response.  Forms authentication is not challenge/response.  I would simply refer to them as "HTTP authentication mechanisms".

Speaking *very* strictly, yes, they are all challenge response mechanisms.  (In basic HTTP authentication or a web form, the "response" would be the user's password.  With a cookie, some magic token would be the "response.")  But realistically, nobody would ever actually call them that - when you talk about a "challenge/response" mechanism, this typically implies that the server provides a **unique** "challenge" that the client then can provide a **unique** "response" to.  (Simple password authentication as in the case of HTTP Basic auth is obviously not unique.)